# Managing Annual Bluegrass (Poa Annua) on a Post-Emergent Basis

Tags: lawn, weed-control

I've looked through the posts regarding managing Annual Bluegrass (Poa Annua) but didn't find what I was looking for.  Most of them suggest dealing with it on a pre-emergent basis in the fall, which I do, but: **1)** I may not be doing it right or in best way (definitely open to suggestions here); and **2)** both of my neighbors have poorly maintained lawns that seed all over mine, i.e. defeating the 'herd immunity' social compact.  Heathens!

What I would *really* like is a way to also treat in spring on a post-emergent basis, but I am finding it quite the challenge to find something that isn't ridiculously cost prohibitive.

So...any thoughts or suggestions? Also, I live in Dallas area and have a (mostly) Bermuda hybrid lawn in a home that is about 20 years old.